# Django QueryDict (request.GET) is empty when I try to pass data from the template to the view

Tags: python, django

Answered in comments. I removed this line: `url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/1')),` and everything magically worked like it is suppose to!

---

So the idea is that a user will click a button. That button will call a JavaScript function. That function will then submit a form. The form will call a certain function in `views.py`.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^[0-9]*$', main, name='main'),
]
```

**index.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'main' %}" method="GET" id="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="my_data" value="myValue">
</form>

<button href="javascript:{}" onclick="callMain();">main</button>
```

**index_script.js**

```
function callMain(){
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```

**views.py**

```
def main(request):
    print(request.GET) #empty dict  <QueryDict: {}>

    #data = request.GET['my_data'] #<------ doesn't work.
    #data = request.GET.get('my_data', '') #doesn't throw error, but still empty.

    return render( ......."settings.html",  {'name': data})
```

Below is the output in the terminal when the button is clicked:

```
[31/Mar/2016 23:17:06] "GET /?my_Data=myValue HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

---

Everything works properly except for the part where `request.GET` is empty. Where are my errors?

---

EDIT:

`index.html` is rendered like this:

```
return render(request, "index.html", {'someContext': "value"})
```

Here is more of the runserver output:

```
[01/Apr/2016 00:46:47] "GET /static/img/1.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[01/Apr/2016 00:46:48] "GET /?my_data=myValue HTTP/1.1" 302 0
<QueryDict: {}>

[01/Apr/2016 00:46:48] "GET /1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2246
```

I believe Line 1 is fetching the image. Line 2 is when I click the button. Line 3 is the print statement in `main()` function. And the final line is the render call at the end of `main()`.

---

Complete `views.py`

```
import re

from django.shortcuts import render
from MyImage.models import MyImage




def main(request):

    print(request.GET)

    image_file = get_image_file(request)

    if (MyImage.objects.filter(name=image_file).exists()):

        image = MyImage.objects.get(name=image_file)
        image.view_count = image.view_count + 1
        image.save()

        return render(request, "index.html", {'image': "img/"+image_file})
    else:
        return render(request, "index.html", {'image': "img/1.png"})


def get_image_file(request):
    i = request.get_full_path()
    i = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", i)
    image_file = i + ".png"
    return image_file
```

Images are stored as `1.png`, `2.png`, `3.png`, etc. So if a user went to www.mysite.com/2, then they should see `2.png`. If the picture doesn't exist, then the default picture is shown instead.

---

Complete `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from .views import main
from django.views.generic import RedirectView



urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/1')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^[0-9]*$', main, name='main'),

]
```

Comment: Can you post the preceding and succeeding lines of the runserver output? I was wondering why the response code is 302 instead of 200.

Comment: How are you rendering `index.html`?

Comment: okay. I added more information. @RodXavier

Comment: I rendered it with render(request, "index.html", {"someContext":"value"}) @mhawke

Comment: Can you also please show the whole `urls.py` as wells as the `views.py`?

Comment: I added them. I'm not sure if you're notified when I edit. @RodXavier

Comment: Why is your `/` a `RedirectView`? That is the reason why the `request.GET` is empty. Django processes the request and matches the url as the index view then redirects to `/1` dispatching all query parameters.

Comment: Ohhh....dang. Yup, you are right.  I added a `RedirectView` because when a user goes to `www.mysite.com`, I want to redirect them to `www.mysite.com/1`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why there is *nothing* in `request.GET`, however, the server access log shows that the query string contains a parameter named `my_Data`.
Due to case sensitivity `my_Data != my_data`.

Perhaps there is a typo in `index.html` where the input tag's `name` attribute is `my_Data` not `my_data`.